# PHP Composer Autoloader Class not Found Exception

Tags: php, composer-php, autoloader

The title speaks itself. So here is my project structure:

```
|src
    |Database
        |Core
            |MySQL.php
        |Support
    start.php
|vendor
composer.json
index.php
```

MySQL.php file:

```
<?php
namespace Database\Core;
//Some methods here
```

index.php and start.php files:

```
//start.php file
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
?>

//index.php file
<?php
use Database\Core;
require __DIR__ . '/src/start.php';

$mysql = new MySQL(); // Gets exception Class 'MySQL' cannot found etc.
?>
```

And finally my composer.json autoload part:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": "Database\\": "src/" // Also tried "src/Database" too
}
```

Where is the problem? I'm really tired of trying to cope with this situation. Please help guys! Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to include namespace when you are initializing a class:

```
$mysql = new Database\Core\MySQL();
```

or

```
use Database\Core\MySQL;
$mysql = new MySQL();
```

See [Using namespaces: Aliasing/Importing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Comment: Thanks I'm really grateful but can't up vote due to low reputation :)

Answer (score 6):

Aside from not using the right `use` statement as already mentioned, PSR-4 does not work like that. It is more of an alias. You are essentially saying that `src` equals `Database`. So to have a directory named `Database` in there would imply that the fully qualified namespace + class equals 'Database\Database\Core\MySQL`. You want to use PSR-0 in this case, or adjust your PSR-4 definition.

Comment: To expand a bit on this good answer: you wouldn't want your namespace to be something generic like "Database". You want to use something that no other php package might already use, so the name of your company/org is a good choice, e.g. if your company is named Acme Baseball Cards, a good namespace might be "AcmeBaseball". In your Mysql.php file then the namespace would be `namespace AcmeBaseball\Database\Core;` and in composer.json `"psr-4": "AcmeBaseball\\": "src/"`  You'll notice this if you install a composer package like AWS Php SDK; open their compser.json and the namespace is `Aws`